# Create a custom scope for a Grails quartz job

Tags: grails

Has anyone managed to create a custom scope in Grails?

I did this in BootStrap.groovy (injected grailsApplication):

grailsApplication.mainContext.getBeanFactory().registerScope('simpleThread', new   SimpleThreadScope())

And in my spring/resources.groovy, I have:

```
myContext(MyContext) { bean ->
    bean.scope = 'simpleThread'
}
```

This then gets injected into all my domain objects.

This seems to work... but there are warnings about objects using SimpleThreadScope not getting destroyed... I am wondering if this is safe.

I do this because I can't use Request scope, because we fire off Quartz jobs (using the Grails plugin), and the request gets destroyed.

We use this context object in both regular web requests and async ones that use Quartz...

Comment: Why can't you use session scope  ? You can define a service and define the scope of it to session. In your controller you can then call the service with the necessary parameters. You may not need the request object because you will have retrieved all your parameters. Hope that helps

Comment: Well, a session scope wouldn't work for two reasons:

Comment: Sorry, it timed out on me ;-)  Thanks for the suggestion, but I want to avoid using session for a few reasons (one is to enable the user to work with multiple tabs in the same browser without strange side effects).  Also, passing parameters to a service won't work, because I need to get information injected into the domain objects (a variable that I want to set once, not something I want to have to set into every created object or pass into every method) - which seems to be a fairly common practice with "context" information.

Comment: Fwiw, the solution seems to work, just didn't know if anyone else had tried it.  In case anyone else can use it, at the end of the Job, I'm cleaning up like this:

Comment: ConfigurableBeanFactory configurableBeanFactory = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBeanFactory()
            configurableBeanFactory.destroyScopedBean('myContext')

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm glad you were able to find it